# Wait video finish to go to the next slide on a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow with pics and videos and when it gets to the video slide, I want it to stop, play the video and waits it finishes. Then it goes ahead to the next slide.

To solve this, I tried use promisses on the function play() of the video element in html5, like the sample over here.

However, the code inside the promisse doesn't execute and on the alert shows undefinied message.

Someone may help me please?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <title>Ricardo Ambrosio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#perfil">QUEM SOU EU?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#programa">COMO FUNCIONA?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#alunos">MEUS ALUNOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#planos">PLANOS E PREÇOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#presencial">ATENDIMENTO PRESENCIAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="img1">
          <img src="/images/banner-1.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="/images/banner-2.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="/images/banner-3.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <video id="video" width="1550" height="500">
          <source src="/videos/443474440.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="w3 button w3-display-left next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
      &#10095;
    </button>
    <button class="w3 button w3-display-left prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
      &#10094;
    </button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
let video = document.getElementById("video");

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);
});

video.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    video.volume = 1;
  } else {
    video.pause();
    video.volume = 0;
  }
});

async function playPause() {
  video.play();
  video.volume = 0;
}

async function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  if (slideIndex == 4) {
    playPause();
  } else {
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you implement slideshow?

Comment: Hey, @Andrej. I edited the code. I kinda solved this way up there =(

Comment: So you've solved the problem then?

Comment: Yes. I`ll close it. Thanks